# xaml parsing error on XP: "0 is not a valid value for Int32"

Tags: .net, wpf, parsing, xaml, converters

Have a client running XP.  They have a little bit of "weirdness" going on with a very simple XAML control once it's instantiated.

NO issues on non-XP machines.  Sporadic issues on a specific customer machines.

Unable to reproduce locally.  Anyone experience this?  It seems like the default type converter is failing for the attached property...but I'm assuming it's a side effect to something else.

ERROR:

> `Cannot convert string '0' in attribute 'Row' to object of type 'System.Int32'.  0 is not a valid value for Int32`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Menu Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
       :
       :
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Since the menu would defalut to row 0 and column 0 regardless, does removing the assignment help?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Unfortunately that may fix this instance of the issue...but any other time I use a Grid.Row="?" or probably any other property="Int32" I'm going to run into this error.  I need to find out the root cause of the issue overall.

Comment: Are you setting or overriding the FrameworkElement Language property? Maybe you're doing that and the language used is causing the problem. If you're using the CurrentCulture or CurrentUICulture then check what language is set for that or the regional settings on the xp system.

Comment: I'm also having this issue. It works fine on all computers except for one client site. We're unable to reproduce it in house and experimenting with international settings on our test machine hasn't helped yet.  I have this msdn case open as well: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/978606f6-e5e8-4302-8f8a-5e353b72ce4b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue may be due to localization and sounds like this issue ([Localization](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/wpf/thread/75a636ed-ae0f-4731-a2ab-6c361b8dc72f)) where row zero was referring to a missing string in another resource which only happened on sets targetting the other language; hence sporadic.